# Cooldown reset/bypass slash command (app_command) on discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have implemented various slash commands that have cooldown, but I am in need of resetting (aka skipping) the cooldown in certain situations.
There is an `app_commands.Cooldown.reset()` that can be used to achieve this. (It says it "resets" the state of the cooldown. Right now I don't know if that means it just skips it or what)
The problem is that I don't quite understand how to reach the cooldown object from within the command function:

Let's say I have a function:

```py
    @app_commands.command(name="...",
                          description="...")
    @app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, per)
    async def function(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        ...
```

It has a cooldown that sometimes needs to be ignored (like if there was an unexpected error)
Directly using `app_commands.Cooldown.reset()` the way I used `ctx.reset_cooldown()` for prefix commands,raises an error saying `self` parameter needs to be passed. In this case `self` refers to the cog the command is in so `app_commands.Cooldown.reset(self)` obviously does not work sice the function needs a Cooldown object to reset,

My intuition tells me that there has to be a way to reference the cooldown from within the interaction, something like `interaction.cooldown.reset()` but I've been searching around the docs and have not seen anything.
I might be probably missing simple, but I can't seem to find a solution.
People are telling me to implement a dyanmic cooldown checker but the data that I need to check to reset the cooldown or not cannot be transfered to the checker function.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally did it!

I used a dynamic cooldown that calls a function that returns a pre-made cooldown object I created elsewhere. The code would look something like this:

```py
    cooldownobj = app_commands.Cooldown(1,per)

    def cooldown_checker(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> Optional[app_commands.Cooldown]:
        return cooldownobj

    @app_commands.command(name="...",
                          description="...")
    @app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown(cooldown_checker)
    async def function(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        ...
        app_commands.Cooldown.reset(cooldownobj) #Resets the cooldown created elsewhere
```